# How to import all vBulletin forum user to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, vbulletin

how to import all vBulletin from user to WordPress so users will only have to sign in once. It doesn’t matter which platform they sign into; once they’ve signed in to one they’re signed into the other. And, no matter which platform they’re looking at, they will be able to see updates to the forum because they will act as a single platform.
Basically how to bridge them .

Answer (score 0):

Basically, redirect logins from WP to vBulletin. When user visits WP, on `init`, check if user is logged in in vBulletin, if he's - check if there is WP user with user meta that is equal to ID of user in vBulletin (doing it like this allows for username/email change on vBulletin side), if there is, do this:

```
wp_set_current_user($userid); 
if(wp_validate_auth_cookie()==FALSE)
{
    wp_set_auth_cookie($userid, true, false);  
}
```

where `$userid` is ID of WP user to which meta with vBulletin ID belongs.
If user does not exist, create new WP user, filling out any necessary details, get ID of newly created user and do the above, but also set user meta mentioned before.